# When does an algebraic differential equation have algebraic solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a rational function. Typically the solution curves of the differential equation
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)
$$
are not algebraic (for example, if $f(x,y)=y$, the solutions are the non-algebraic curves $y=ce^x$). There are certain $f$, however, for which all solutions are algebraic (for example, if $f$ is a rational function in just $x$, having $0$ residue at every pole).

> Given $f$, is there a way to check whether all the solutions to $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ are algebraic?

Comment: I don't think so, since if y' is a rational function, y could be rational, algebraic, logarithmic, trigonometric, inverse trigonometric or many other things

Comment: Just a tongue-in-cheek answer: a good way to check would be solving the equation.

Comment: This problem has a long and storied history going back to the 1800s in Berlin: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183551413 . Although this brief history doesn't contain detailed statements of the results, it might help you with where to look.

Comment: I'd attack such a problem by using Picard-Vessiot theory (see the first chapter of [Singer and van der Put](https://singer.math.ncsu.edu/papers/dbook2.ps)) to determine if the equation can be solved with integrals, then apply the Risch algorithm to solve the integrals.